# Binding is not updated as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, user-controls

I'm building a simple **UserControl**, **DoubleDatePicker**, which defines a **DependencyProperty**, **SelectedDate** :

**DoubleDatePicker.xaml** :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfDoubleDatePicker.DoubleDatePicker"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">    
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="DateInput" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
    <toolkit:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

**DoubleDatePicker.xaml.cs** :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace TestWpfDoubleDatePicker
{
    public partial class DoubleDatePicker : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DoubleDatePicker), null);

        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime)this.GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
        }

        public DoubleDatePicker()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to bind the **SelectedDate** property from the outside but things do not seem so simple.
Here is a sample code that is trying to get the value of the property in a **TextBlock** :

**MainWindow.xaml** :

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfDoubleDatePicker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfDoubleDatePicker"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <local:DoubleDatePicker x:Name="ddp" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
    <Button Content="Update" Click="Button_Click" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and **MainWindow.xaml.cs** :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfDoubleDatePicker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MainWindow), null);

        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime)this.GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SelectedDate = this.ddp.SelectedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the **DoubleDatePicker** itself all is working fine : the **SelectedDate** property is updated when changed by using any of the two **DatePicker**, and the **TextBlock** of the **DoubleDatePicker** is updated as expected.

But, outside, the **TextBlock** of the **MainWindow** is not updated automatically and the only way to get the **SelectedDate** property of the **DoubleDatePicker** is to get it explicitly, like it's done when clicking the **Button**.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2010 with WPF 4.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is overwriting your DataContext inside your control with this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Now your DatePicker no longer binds to your intended object, but in stead binds to your DatePicker instance. I guess this is not how you intended your DatePicker to work ;).

So, remove that line in your DatePicker, and if you do need to bind inside the XAML of your DatePicker use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` bindings to bind to this dependency property.

Hope this clarifies things ;)

I took the liberty of rewriting your bindings inside your XAML of your DatePicker using ElementName bindings:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfDoubleDatePicker.DoubleDatePicker"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
x:Name="Root">    
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="DateInput" SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDate}" />
    <toolkit:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I have removed the DataContext assignment line and used binding with ElementName : nothing is broken inside the UserControl but from the outside I'm still unable to get the value updating automatically. Something is missing but I don't guess what.

Comment: When using your dependency property try this: SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}" . Its probably not TwoWay default. You can make it TwoWay default though a FrameworkPropertyMetaData class.